# how to access raw data in opensearchserver?

Tags: database, search-engine

I searched for documents and cannot find where it store all data. 
I want to access all crawled data in order to do my own processing.

Answer (score 0):

In the file [StartStopListener](http://sourceforge.net/p/opensearchserve/code/1805/tree/trunk/src/java/com/jaeksoft/searchlib/web/StartStopListener.java) it sets up the index directories: look for the value of the environment values **OPENSEARCHSERVER_DATA**, **OPENSEARCHSERVER_MULTIDATA**, or **OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR**.

Now, whether you'll be able to parse the files easily/correctly is another debate: I haven't ever tried to directly open a search server's indexes by hand, and I don't know that the index format is well documented.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the crawled data are not stored. Only the extracted text is stored. It is possible to store the crawled data, here is the process:

1. Create a new field: Set the "stored" parameter to yes or to compressed.
2. Go to the Schema / Parser List
3. Edit the HTML parser
4. In the  "Field Mapping" tab, link the parser field "htmlSource" to the new field.

Restart the indexation process. Now, all crawled data will be copied to this field. Don't forget to add it as returned field in your query.

Comment: Thanks, But I cannot find htmlSource in Field mapping tab. There're title body meta_* internal_* external_* lang filename content_type. I'm using v1.2.4

Comment: Sorry, it is an 1.3 feature. The new version is now pretty stable. The RC1 has just been released on [Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opensearchserve/)

Comment: Got it! thank you. But is there any other way to get all raw data except query api?